# More settings option does not show when printing from Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, printing

I am going to save a web page as PDF on Google Chrome, but the "More settings" option is not shown as below.

[image]

When changed to another printer, the "More settings" option is shown.

[image]

Why is the "More settings" option not shown when "Save as PDF" is selected? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like [the @page CSS rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page) may be interfering with the "Save as PDF" printing option, removing it from the webpage's stylesheets would fix the issue in that case, so pull up inspect element on your webpage  of concern and search for any instances of that rule in its theming resources and remove them.

Comment: Sharing my experience. In my case, `@page { size: A4 }` inhibited "More settings" and forced the user to print A4. Removing this, "More settings" re-appeared, but now the user can select any number of page sizes potentially incompatible with my fixed-aspect-ratio layout. Ideally, I want to restrict the user to : A4, A5, legal, tabloid or at the very least provide A4 as the default. Seems like it's all or one =(.

Comment: Perhaps for your case @Kalnode, you could use dedicated "Print in XXX" buttons for each page size, with the default CTRL+P behavior being printing in A4 as you intend, while each button changes the applied printing-related CSS accordingly via JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking this. It may be what we need as our end-users are technicians but they still need some hand-holding.

Answer (score 1):

I suffer from the same problem¬frustrated  
Now it is solved in this way: simply restart chrome in another new window, or restart your window system and open a new window for chrome.